# Embed google sheets w/o updating source

Tags: javascript, php, web, google-sheets, embed

I have a published Google sheet and I would like to use it in a website.

What I want is to have something such a "local copy" of that sheet, that is when I update sheet on my website the update remain local.

I will use this sheet for an order form, so every user of my website should have a empty version of sheet.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: So essentially you want a different sheet for each user accessing the web app? Please provide more information. Read [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a a proposal & I hope it works in your case.

Separate the file into Master sheet (Sheet1) & Input Sheet (Sheet2)

File A contains Sheet1&2

File B contains Sheet2 only

Share only file B on the website.
But (when the time comes to sync the info) copy File B Sheet2 content to File A Sheet2. And all the formula inside it (Master sheet) should work just fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for proposal but it doesn't work because sharing File B with sheet2 in the website make 2 contemporary users to see the same sheet with the same content. I would like to separate in this way:

- User A edit sheet

- User B edit sheet

 - The update of User A must not be visible by User B and vice versa.

Comment: you mean.. "User A edit sheet1 - User B edit sheet1"  ?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly this. I would like to have a "template" sheet that will not be updated by any user.

Comment: I think [this](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/22231997/establish-a-google-sheet-as-a-template-and-allow-multiple-users-to-update-and-save-as-unique-files?hl=en) is your answer..

Comment: Does it suits your case?

Comment: Yes it suits! Unfortunately I'm inside an iframe and changing /edit to /template/preview I got:

Refused to display 'https://docs.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: Then this answer post no longer serve its purpose..  3 options : [edit] this question | Create new question (the iframe question) | or ask the source [https://support.google.com/docs/community?hl=en]